# How does Visual Studio turn false to true (via Timer Events perhaps)?

Tags: visual-c++, timer, event-handling, visual-studio-debugging

For an hour or so I have been trying to explain some very disturbing behaviour, unsure whether it was caused by Visual Studio's compiler or its debugger. I now know part of the answer. Essentially I have the following compiled and running in a MSVC2005 Debug build:

```
DWORD timeStamp;
struct SomeEventStruct {
  DWORD timeStamp;
  // ... plus other data
};
void Magic( const SomeEventStruct & anEvent )
{
    if ( anEvent.timeStamp < timeStamp )
    {
      ASSERT( false ); // shouldn't happen! Time does not run backwards!
    }
    timeStamp = anEvent.timeStamp;
}
```

The only way the `ASSERT( false )` can even execute is if the `if` expression evaluates as true, right? So how is it that when the `ASSERT()` fires, and I break into the debugger to inspect the values of variables, I often find that `timeStamp` is 0? By definition, this cannot be possible - an unsigned value can never be less than zero.

Admittedly, this is a multi-threaded application, but no other thread touches these variables - it is all within the main UI thread. Also I've simplified the situation - they are actually member variables and functions, not that I think that matters. What I believe is relevant is that the variable values were reasonable the first time the `ASSERT()` fired and invited me to break into the debugger, where I found a bad time stamp. It was only after continuing that that things started going weird.

Eventually, I discovered that the timeStamp value was being reset to zero between the `if` statement and the `ASSERT( false )` statement. I know that the only line of code that possibly does this is ultimately connected to a timer event (distinct from the time-stamped events above - the timer fires to refresh a display of the system events I'm interested in).

So now I want to know: do windows timer events act like interrupts, suspending thread execution at some point, then returning to it at a later time... or is something else going on here that is particular to the VS debugger, or to the internal workings of `ASSERT()`? If I want to prevent my timer event handler running until a previous invocation has finished, is it up to me to prevent that re-entrancy?

Comment: One thing is for sure: it's nothing to do with Visual Studio!

Comment: @Kieren - is that sarcasm? ;-) The first thing I did when I encountered this was a "Rebuild All" because weird results often occur when VS tries to do an incremental build instead of a full rebuild.